# calc vs box-sizing in layout?

Tags: css, layout

I have seen articles that talk about using the `calc` function for layout. (Like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/knfme/1/)** )

```
div
{
    height: calc( 100% - 128px);
}
```

**My question is**:

Are there any benefits of doing this with calc over doing it with the `box-sizing` property
(Apart from the neater code)

(Like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/2/)**)

```
div
{
    margin-top: -64px;
    padding-top: 64px;

    margin-bottom: -64px;
    padding-bottom: 64px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

... because seemingly `box-sizing:border-box` is better because of its wider browser support?

Answer (score 2):

Calc is a lot more flexible and solves a number of scenarios that `border-box` does not cover. But as you already know browser support is limited, so if `border-box` solves your problem, then you should use it.

Comment: I know that calc can be used in other ways including complex operations with division etc.However regarding calc use **specifically in layout** - it's usually just 100% - x px. ... which can be done with box-sizing. Can you think of a scenario where calc would be necesarry?

Comment: @Danield - no I can't. If it can be done with `box-sizing`, then do it with `box-sizing`. Maybe when `calc` has better browser support this question might have a different answer (although I suspect even then, `box-sizing` will be a better answer for performance reasons), but for now there's simply no real question about which one to use.